# Html Agility Pack ends-with does not work

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, html

I tried to use `ends-with` in Html Agility Pack in the following mode: `//span[ends-with(@id, 'Label2')]` and  `//span[ends-with(., 'test')]` , but it does not work.

All other functions, like `starts-with` and `contains` work well.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you asking a question here?

Comment: @Arnis L., I had forgot to add it. He was correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There can be found a hack!
It is something like this:

//span['Label2'=substring(@id, string-length(@id)-string-length('_Label2')+1)]

Answer (score 3):

Yes; it isn't supported, neither here nor in `XmlDocument`. Perhaps iterate manually over `//span[@id]`?

```
foreach (var node in from HtmlNode n in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@"//span[@id]")
                     where n.GetAttributeValue("id","").EndsWith("Label2")
                     select n)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(node.OuterHtml);
 }
```

Comment: I thinks I'll have to implement a hard-coded solution, like one you propose, if none is recommending any other 'patch'.